# Resolve local DNS names from DHCP server? (NetworkManager touble)

Tags: dns, fedora, dhcp, networkmanager

I have a machine running Fedora acting as a LAN/WAN gateway that runs dnsmasq as a DHCP server for the LAN. This works great for the clients, but the gatway machine itself is unable to resolve names of machines on the LAN.

The trouble is that NetworkManager insists on configuring `resolf.conf` to use the WAN DNS first. If I use `nslookup` to force use of localhost (127.0.0.1) as the DNS server, I can resolve names of machines on the LAN just fine.

I've tried setting `dns=dnsmasq` and fiddling with `ipv4.dns-priority` to no avail; NM still makes the WAN DNS servers¹ first. How do I make NM use localhost (127.0.0.1) as the first DNS server?

(¹ I'm not sure if it matters, but apparently I am getting an IPv6 DNS server frpm the WAN connection. Also if it matters, the "WAN" is actually a LinkSys router.)

**Edit:**

It turns out `dns=dnsmasq` is no good; NM won't start it if the "real" dnsmasq is running (almost certainly because it can't bind to the in-use ports), and NM's version doesn't seem to want to supply DHCP (at least, if I copy the DHCP server config from `/etc/dnsmasq.d` to `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`, NM's dnsmasq quits coming up.) So it seems I really, really need to force the local system to prefer the LAN DNS servers over the WAN DNS servers. Which... *should* be `ipvx.dns-priority` IIUC, except fiddling with those does not seem to have any effect .